# Multiple constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

Question is about multiple constructors that confuses me.

```
#include "complex.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(double realPart, double imPart)
    : m_R(realPart), m_I(imPart)
{
    cout << "complex(" << m_R << "," << m_I << ")" << endl;
}

Complex::Complex(double realPart)
{
    Complex(realPart, 0);
}

Complex::Complex() : m_R(0.0), m_I(0.0)
{
}

int main() {
    Complex C1;
    Complex C2(3.14);
    Complex C3(6.2, 10.23);
}
```

Can someone explain how compiler knows which constructor to use of three defined? Primer is from [this book](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780131879058/downloads/0131879057_Ezust_book.pdf), page 58.

Comment: It matches the parameters

Comment: Look at number of argument and take better match according to its argument type.

Comment: This can also be called constructor overloading.

Comment: It's done by *overload resolution*.

Answer (score 20):

**Side Note**

If you want to utilize C++ 11 delegating constructors you should write:

```
Complex::Complex(double realPart) 
:    Complex(realPart, 0)
{}
```

instead of

```
Complex::Complex(double realPart) {
    Complex(realPart, 0);
    }
```

which creates a temporary unused `Complex` inside the constructor body.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the number and types of arguments supplied to the constructor.  Thus

```
std::Complex first(1, 2.0); // Use first constructor
std::Complex second(5.0);   // Use second constructor
std::Complex third;         // Use third constructor with no arguments.
```